# testing client side javascript on the command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I am working on a project which has a lot of client side javascript files

none of these files have any module.export.XXX statements

I understand that jasmine has a stand-alone version which uses a html file to run the tests and a node.js version which uses the cli to run the tests.

When using the stand-alone version of jasmine i can import the js files i want to test with  tags, no problem.

When using the node.js version i cannot use import statements because none of the files that i wish to test have exports.

I am very keen on testing on the command line so that running the tests with our continuous integration package is easier.

I have attempted to solve this using this guide
https://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2013/02/automatically-unit-testing-client-side-javascript-with-jasmine-and-node-js/
however it is very out of date (the jasmine folder structure is different) and i could not fix the JDOM issue which is mentioned.

Is there any way to make this work other than adding export statements?
if no
will adding export statements cause issues in any browsers?
and
most of the existing files are a wrapper functions with all of the functions and other components (variables, event listeners ect) inside it. I intend to call specific individual functions found in the files (not the wrapper functions) from the tests. will this be possible without using prototypes?
will i need to change the architecture

Comment: Have you heard about mocha, sinon and chai? All of them JS. Would recommend them for unit tests.

Comment: can mocha (or any other js test framework) run client side js (scripts with no exports) from a test which is executed on the command line?